# External script not loading on page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to add a Trustpilot widget to my Gatsby.js website. It is required to load an external script from Trustpilot CDN.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
```

I have tried multiple ways to add this script to my component. The first thing I tried was React Helmet. I added using the following code:

```
<Helmet>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async></script>
```

The script seems to load when I initially load a page. Once I navigate to a different page, the styling goes away. As I reload, it comes back.

I tried adding the script inside componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
    var addScript = document.createElement('script');
    addScript.setAttribute('src', '//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js');
    document.body.appendChild(addScript);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your script (or any other component) to be persistent through your site, you need to use `wrapPageElement` or `wrapRootElement` APIs. Both APIs are suggested to be placed in `gatsby-browser.js` as well as in `gatsby-ssr.js`

*Disclaimer: `componentDidMount()` will be triggered every time the DOM tree is loaded, it won't work for your use-case.*

The issue here is that you are adding a non-React asset, not a component. You can try:

```
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element, props }) => {
  return <SomeWrapper {...props}>{element}</SomeWrapper>;
};
```

Then, create a component called `SomeWrapper` and place your `<Helmet>`:

```
const SomeWrapper = (props) =>{
 return <div>
           <Helmet>
             <script type="text/javascript" src="//widget.trustpilot.com/bootstrap/v5/tp.widget.bootstrap.min.js" async /> 
          </Helmet>
          {props.children}
    </div>
}
```

Comment: did not work me, still have to refresh the page for the script to reload

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem with a react-based site. Trustpilot has specific instructions for how to handle both class & hook based react projects. Once I implemented that, it fixed things for me.

Here's the instructions link:
https://support.trustpilot.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011421468--Add-a-TrustBox-widget-to-a-single-page-application#add-a-trustbox-widget-with-a-react-application-1

I would add their instructions for React, but I don't know if it's copywriting to do that, so just check the pg.